# RMarkdown: How can I wrap a table (made with kable) in text when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to wrap a table in text and ran into multiple problems:

When trying to just simply position the figure to the left, the caption does not get left-aligned as well and stays centered (which defeats the purpose of left aligning):

````
```{r table-Verbrauch-USB}
kable(USB_Summary2018, booktabs = TRUE, caption = 'Antibiotikaverbrauch in DDDs des Jahres 2018')%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position", position = "left")
```
````

How it looks:
[image]

When trying to use the `"float_left"` command as specified in the kable_styling options, it looks like this (note: I had to delete the `latex_options = "hold_position`, it wouldn't knit otherwise):

[image]

I have no idea what is happening to my table with `float_left`, but it seems to completly break it.

If important, my yaml-header:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
lang: de
geometry: margin = 1in
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} #Options: singlespacing, onehalfspacing, doublespacing
- \usepackage{chngcntr}
- \counterwithout{figure}{section}
- \counterwithout{table}{section}
- \usepackage{microtype}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{float}
- \floatplacement{figure}{H}
- \floatplacement{table}{H}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
---
```

Can anybody tell me how I can have a table that is wrapped in text?

Edit: If anybody needs sample data to solve the problem, I would gladly provide it!

Comment: Hi Hurlikus I would like to see the code that solved this issue as I am trying to accomplish something similar!